# Joining Table with no unique values

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a date/unique ID table to streamline some of the other queries we need to run as a team. Basically I have a set of value ('A','B','C',...etc)
and need add a date to each value so the result would look something like:

I have a table a all my dates and all my IDs, can I join them and end a result like the below:

```
    Date ID
    1/1/2018 A
    1/1/2018 B
    1/1/2018 C
    1/1/2018 ..etc
    1/2/2018 A
    1/2/2018 B
    1/2/2018 C
    1/2/2018 ..etc
```

I know I can create table in excel or something and insert it, but as more values are added I'd like to be able to rerun the script to generate the values. 
Is this possible?

Edit - cross join worked perfectly

```
   select date, id from cal (cross join distinct id from source) t1
```

Comment: if you have a table `dates` of dates and `ids` of id values, something like `SELECT d.date, i.id FROM dates d CROSS JOIN ids i` should work

Comment: can you show us the tables that you want to join?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the expected result:

```
-- query to get the result in case the columns in the same table.
SELECT t_dates.Date, t_ids.ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM table_name
) t_dates, (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table_name
) t_ids
ORDER BY t_dates.Date ASC, t_ids.ID ASC

-- query to get the result in case the columns are in different tables.
-- this is also possible with the same table.
SELECT DISTINCT t_dates.Date, t_ids.ID 
FROM table_name1 t_dates, table_name2 t_ids
ORDER BY t_dates.Date ASC, t_ids.ID ASC
```

You can also [create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html):

```
-- creating the view
CREATE VIEW table_id AS
SELECT t_dates.Date, t_ids.ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM table_name
) t_dates, (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table_name
) t_ids

-- using the view
SELECT * FROM table_id
```